# Android TabLayout no layout works on all devices

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm using a TabLayout, and no matter what layout options I choose, it looks bad somewhere.  Here's what I've tried, and the results:

> Gravity center, mode scrollable: if there is too much space
>   horizontally on the screen, the tab bar doesn't fill the width
>
> Gravity center, mode fixed: if there is not enough space, the text
>   wraps (which would be OK except it's the last letter of a single word.
>   Looks ridiculous.
>
> Gravity fill, mode fixed: if not enough space, text wraps

Documentation says fill/scrollable is invalid, which is unfortunate because it seems like that's exactly what I need - fill all available space, and scroll if there is not enough. I tried it anyway, and it doesn't fill.

I have tried setting `tabMaxWidth` to 0dp with all these combinations, and it doesn't seem to have any effect.  I have tried various solutions I've found around here with doing things in `styles.xml` or in code, with no success.  Is there just no way to get this thing to behave on all screens?  Do I need to calculate the screen width and adjust the layout at runtime (barf)?

UPDATE: I decided to try measuring and adujsting.  Here's the code:

```
tabLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {


        tabLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        final int tabWidth = tabLayout.getWidth();

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        if(screenWidth > tabWidth){
            // The tabs won't fill the horizontal space.  Switch to fixed mode instead of scrollable.
            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        }
    }
});
```

What happens is the screen width and tab layout width are the same.  So this technique cannot help me distinguish whether there's not enough or too much space.  I tried it with the TabLayout width set to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` and that didn't work either.  Still looking for a solution.

EDIT: Here are screenshots of the behavior.

[image: Tabs are not taking up the full width]

[image: Text is wrapping]

If I can get the white behind the tab layout to be gray that would probably be good enough, but I think that's the activity / application background color, and I don't want to change that to gray.

Here's the background setting in the XML: `app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"`

That leads to:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background"/>
</selector>
```

`tab_background` is `#a2a2a3`

Comment: where are screenshots?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Screenshots added.  I don't know if it's significant but the device where the text wraps is running Android 5, and the other is on 7.

Comment: use scrollable and set the tabLayout as match_parent with the background color you want. It's the best solution for all screens and used throughout any app I have seen that has more than 1 or 2 tabs

Comment: @mobilepotato7 How do I set the background color for the tab layout separate from the background color for the activity?  The `tabBackground` color is gray, and there's white showing behind that.

Comment: @nasch in the tabLayout view itself. For example:

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

Comment: @mobilepotato7 That did it! or at least a "good enough" solution.  The tabs still don't fill the space but it's not really noticeable in my case.  Thank you.  Hopefully someone can post a more universal solution because this one may not work as well for everyone.